# Terminate cat command immediately after using in C

Tags: c, cat, tty

So I am communicating with a device by using echo to send and cat to receive. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
fp = popen("echo "xyz" > /dev/ttyACM0 | cat - /dev/ttyACM0", "r");
while (fgets(ret_val, sizeof(ret_val)-1, fp) != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(ret_val, "response") == 0)
    {
       close(fp);
       return ret_val;
    }
}
```

Ok, The problem is, cat seems to stay open, because when I run this code in a loop, it works the first time, then hangs at the spot I call popen. Am I correct in assuming cat is the culprit?

Is there a way to terminate cat as soon as I run the command, so I just get the response from my device? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a pipe? The output of `echo` goes to the device, so nothing will be written to the pipe.

Comment: `cat` keeps reading until it gets EOF. If the device doesn't send EOF after the response, how is it supposed to know when it has read the whole response?

Comment: Why are you using external commands for this in the first place? Just open `/dev/ttyACM0` in your C program.

Comment: Like @Barmar said, there's absolutely no reason to use `popen` to write to / read from a serial port.  You can use `fopen`, `fputs` and `fgets`.  If you need to change baudrate or other properties of the serial port, see `tcgetattr` man page.

Comment: Other minor issues: 1) `-1` not needed in `sizeof(ret_val)-1`.  2) Suspect you want `"response\n"` and not `"response"`.

Comment: Thanks @BrianMcFarland and everyone, I switched to fopen and i've made some progress, but I think I need to mess around with the Serial port properties. There are actually 2 devices I am communicating with, and the serial properties I use for one causes the other to freeze up, So I need to do more research on configuring the correct properties. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the command:

```
echo "xyz" > /dev/ttyACM0 | cat - /dev/ttyACM0
```

TTY devices normally do not open until carrier is present, or CLOCAL is set.  The cat could be waiting on open.  Assuming the device opens, then the cat will hang waiting to read characters until either (1) it receives an EOF character such as control-D, or (2) carrier is lost or (3) you kill it.

Another problem here is that the pipe between echo and cat immediately closes, because the output of the echo is redirected to the same TTY device, and the redirection closes the pipe.

Generally TTY devices are ornery beasts and require special handling to get the logic right.   Probably you are better to read up on TTY devices especially:

```
man termios
```

If you are doing something REALLY SIMPLE, you might get by with:

```
fp = popen("echo 'xyz' >/dev/ttyACM0 & (read x; echo \"$x\")");
```

Keep in mind that both the echo and the read might hang waiting for carrier and that you will get at most one line of output from the popen, and the read could hang waiting for an EOL character.

This whole approach is fraught with problems.  TTY devices require delicate care.  You are using a hammer in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to kill the process launched by `popen`, as there's no API to get the pid -- there's only `pclose` which waits until it ends of its own account (and youe should *ALWAYS* use `pclose` instead of `fclose` to close a `FILE *` opened by `popen`.)

Instead, you're probably better off not using `popen` at all -- just use `fopen` and write what you want with fputs:

```
fp = fopen("/dev/ttyACM0", "r+");
fputs("xyz\n", fp);   // include the newline explicitly
fflush(fp);           // always flush after writing before reading
while (fgets(ret_val, sizeof(ret_val)-1, fp) != NULL) {
           :
```